# C++ pointers query

Tags: c++, pointers

This is my very simple introductory code to C++ pointers,

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    int *p = 0, numbers[5];

    *p = 10;
    *(p+1) = 20;
    *(p+2) = 30;
    *(p+3) = 30;
    *(p+4) = 40;

    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        numbers[i] = *(p + i);

    for (int i = 1; i < sizeof(numbers); i++)
        std::cout << numbers[i] << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

I am running this in Xcode and it shows "build succeeded" but gives me stack output and doesn't show me the actual result.

Comment: Dereferencing `p` is undefined behaviour. Adding 2 (or maybe even 1 in this case) or more to it is also undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointers are variables which store a number, like any other, but because you tell the compiler it is a pointer, the compiler allows you to use that value as an address of things in memory and the language provides "dereferencing" as a way of saying "the value AT the address this variable describes".

Imagine you're going to the airport to catch a flight. You grab a post-it note and write down your flight number, and you take a second post-it with you for your gate.

The first post it is a "flight*" pointer and your second is a "gate*" but right now the gate* pointer is empty.

When you get to the airport, you look up your flight on the board and jot down the gate number. "3A". Now your gate* post-it is valid.

But the post-it itself is NOT your gate, it just points to it: you still have to "dereference" the post-it note to get to your flight - that is, walk across the airport to gate 3A :)

In programming, a variable can't be empty, so it has been agreed upon that a pointer with an address of 0 is "null" and "illegal". Programs crash when they attempt to use a null pointer. By convention there is a macro called "NULL" in C which is intended to distinguish "empty pointer" from the value 0. C++ inherited this but in C++11 they have introduced a new constant, "nullptr".

Your code opens with this:

```
int *p = 0;
```

Which catches a lot of people out. It looks like the same syntax as when we assign through a pointer:

```
*p = 10;
```

But what is actually happening is that you are declaring a variable p which is of type "int *"  and assigning a value to p, not *p.

```
int *p;
p = 0;
*p = 10;
```

You need to point "p" at some integers for storage, either:

```
p = numbers;
```

but this will make p point to the same storage as numbers. But realize, then, that operations like

```
numbers[i] = *(p+i);
```

are now redundant -- `if (p == numbers)` then `*(p+i)` is the same as saying `numbers[i]`.

Answer (score 4):

Make `p` point to a valid memory location before dereferencing

`p = numbers;`

And, following won't be required.

```
for(int i=1;i<5;i++)
    numbers[i]=*(p+i);
```

Also, `i` should start with 0 in for-loop