# C Language: Way to access a field in a structure, within a structure (bit tricky this one)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, structure

We have an header file with these structures declared:

```
typedef struct{
    unsigned short rgb[3];

}PIXEL_T;

typedef struct{
    int format;
    int nrows;
    int ncolumns;
    int max_color;
    PIXEL_T **pixels;

}PBM_T;
```

And we're trying to access the rgb[0] field to write a number to it. But since we're newbies, working with a "pointer of pointers" array is proving difficult. Here's our best, wrong attempt:

```
/*pbm was previously declared as a PBM_T structure. rows and columns are auxiliary       variables to send to the nrows and ncolumns field. we're suppose to create a bitmap matrix*/

pbm->(**pixels) = malloc(sizeof(int *)*rows);
if (pbm->(**pixels) == NULL)
ERROR(ERR_ALLOC,"Error allocating memory for the bitmap matrix");

int i;

for(i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
    pbm->pixels[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*columns);
    }

    pbm->&nrows = rows;
    pbm->&ncolumns = columns;

    while((getline(&line, &len, file_stream)) != 1) {
    getline(&line, &len, file_stream);
    sscanf(line,"%d",&pbm->pixels[i][j]->rgb[0]); /* i and j are for two for cycles we're going to implement */
    }
```

Basically our biggest problem is the proper way to access that field. All the *'s and &'s confuse us a lot. If someone could also give a brief explanation on how it works, we'd be very grateful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Regarding how they work read my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602300/c-pointers-when-new-functions-are-called/19602433#19602433 may help full

Comment: thank you for the feedback. we get the meaning of the & and * operators, it just gets confusing when we're suppose to use them to access structure fields, especially those '**' ones.

Comment: Your majesty, the `*` and `&` operators, as well as parentheses, cannot be applied to field names, as in e.g. `pbm->&nrows` or `pbm->(**pixels)`. Kindly leave them out, your subjects will thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No dereferencing, just plain and simple

```
pbm->pixels = malloc(sizeof(PIXEL_T *)*rows);
```

and

```
if (pbm->pixels == NULL) ...
```

*and*

```
pbm->pixels[i] = malloc(sizeof(PIXEL_T)*columns);
```

Do note that I change the type used for the allocations. You allocate for `int*` and `int` respectively. This wont work, especially for the last, as three `short` are most likely *larger* than a single `int`.

Comment: I see. What about the sscanf? am I accessing the fields properly?
sscanf(line,"%d",&pbm->pixels[i][j]->rgb[0])

Comment: @Digriz If you check an [operator precedence table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) you will see that both structure-pointer dereference (`->`) and array subscripting (`[]`) have higher precedence than the address-of operator (`&`), so that should be fine. And the `pixel` member indexing is fine too, since a pointer can be indexed as an array.

Comment: Three `short` are *probably* larger than a single `int`. (I've never seen a system where that's not true, but you should use the correct type regardless.)

Comment: I get this error when compiling: 
error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘PIXEL_T’)
referencing this line: 
sscanf(line,"%d",&pbm->pixels[i][j]->rgb[0]);
what does this mean?

Comment: @Digriz Ah yes, that because `pixel[i][j]` is not a pointer, so you have to use the normal structure dot accessor `.`, like `&pbm->pixels[i][j].rgb[0]`

Comment: thank you so much! of course this solves only part of the program, we're not really sure if we're saving the bitmap to the matrix anyway. thank you for your time